# What's the purpose of `do` in the while loop?

Tags: ruby

A `while` loop works with or without `do`. Please explain why the following two snippets works the same way.

- Without `do`

  ```
  i = 1
  while i < 5
    i = i + 1
  end
  ```
- With `do`

  ```
  i = 1
  while i < 5 do 
    i = i + 1
  end
  ```

Comment: can anyone please point to the source?

Comment: Don't ask me. ......

Comment: Voting is anonymous. You cannot tell who voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-theoretical answer is quite simply: because the [Ruby Syntax Guide said so](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#while).

The language syntax guide defines the `do` keyword as optional for both `while` and `until` loops.

From what I understand - and it is mostly a theory - allowing the `do` to be optional rather than required is mostly for compatibility and allowing for harmonic syntax within the language.

I think of it as an acknowledgment for the "gray" areas, where things are less absolute. The same is done in physics, where light behaves both as a particle and as a wave and we should acknowledge both aspects.

Coming from different languages and school of thought, `while` is somewhere between a pure keyword (like `if`) and a method (like `loop`, which is defined under the Kernel module)

`if` statements do not require a `do` to begin a block of code and under the same logic, `while` loops wouldn't require a `do` keyword.

This is `while` as a keyword.

On the other hand, [`loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) requires the `do` keyword (or the `{block}`), so why shouldn't `while` have the same semantics?

This is `while` as a method (as far as syntax goes).

Ruby is about making the programmer happy. Allowing the `do` to be optional makes all programmers happy and doesn't require that the Ruby programmer resign themselves to just one school of thought related to the nature of `while`.

Comment: you made me cry and laugh at the same time :D

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 0
while x<3 do puts "hello"; x+=1 end

--output:--
hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: By the way, I suggest you never write code like that, so you can safely forget about the `do`. And because while loops are virtually never used in ruby, you can forget about while loops entirely while you're at it. And, for-loops are never used by rubyists, so don't bother learning that one either. The loops you want to learn are each(), times(), upto(), and downto().

Comment: why they are never used! any reason?

Comment: @gates, Yes! `while` loops are eclipsed by `each()` loops because each() loops are easier to program with.  For instance, if you are stepping through an array, you don't have to know the length of the array or increment a count when you use an each() loop.   And a `for-loop` calls each() internally, so rubyists just call each() directly.  The other loops I mentioned can be used instead of a while loop when counting is needed for some reason, and they are easier to write.

Answer (score -1):

The `do` is optional, and can be used to clarify a code as in the answer to be on one line. Separation can be done with a `do`, newline, `\`, or semicolon.

Comment: "clarify a code to be on one line"--Not clear what you mean.

Comment: `do`, newline, ` \ `, and semicolon are not the same.